# Add data to the table with the least number of rows (15 TABLES )

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add NewJoiner Name and Position to the table with the least number of rows. Also I'd like VBA to return me the name of table in which it has been added.

So the code would count eventually count each rows of the 15 tables and add the Name and Position to the table with least rows and return the number or name of the table using the MsgBox function.

Sorry if it is a silly question, I literraly started VBA 2 days ago, and learnt a lot through this community.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ssNewJoinerM()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Dim ws6 As Worksheet
Dim ws7 As Worksheet
Dim ws8 As Worksheet


Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
Set ws3 = ActiveSheet
Set ws4 = ActiveSheet
Set ws5 = ActiveSheet
Set ws6 = ActiveSheet
Set ws7 = ActiveSheet
Set ws8 = ActiveSheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly Movements")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Howard-Marle Hub")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bernard Hub")
Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Thomas Hub")
Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Michael Hub")
Set ws6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oliver Hub")
Set ws7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lance Hub")
Set ws8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("John Hub")

Dim table1 As ListObject
Dim table2 As ListObject
Dim table3 As ListObject
Dim table4 As ListObject
Dim table5 As ListObject
Dim table6 As ListObject
Dim table7 As ListObject
Dim table8 As ListObject
Dim table9 As ListObject
Dim table10 As ListObject
Dim table11 As ListObject
Dim table12 As ListObject
Dim table13 As ListObject
Dim table14 As ListObject
Dim table15 As ListObject

Set table1 = ws2.ListObjects("Table1")
Set table2 = ws2.ListObjects("Table2")
Set table3 = ws1.ListObjects("Table3")
Set table4 = ws3.ListObjects("Table4")
Set table5 = ws3.ListObjects("Table5")
Set table6 = ws4.ListObjects("Table6")
Set table7 = ws4.ListObjects("Table7")
Set table8 = ws5.ListObjects("Table8")
Set table9 = ws5.ListObjects("Table9")
Set table10 = ws6.ListObjects("Table10")
Set table11 = ws6.ListObjects("Table11")
Set table12 = ws7.ListObjects("Table12")
Set table13 = ws7.ListObjects("Table13")
Set table14 = ws8.ListObjects("Table14")
Set table15 = ws8.ListObjects("Table15")


 Dim NewJoiner As String
 NewJoiner = InputBox("Enter new joiner name in the following format (Surname, First Name)", "Adding New Joiner to Hub")
 Dim Position As String
 Position = InputBox("Enter new joiner Position (A, C, SC, PC, MP, Partner, Admin, Analyst, Director)", "Assigning New Joiner to a position")
 'Input Name and Position and stores it (Could be improved with user form...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do pretty much the same as @FunThomas, he just beat me to it, but I thought I'd post it anyways, as it doesn't use a function plus it shows how to omit certain tables:

```
Sub FindSmallestTable()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim sht As Worksheet

'Loop through each sheet and table in the workbook
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects 'loop through all tables
        'To omit certain tables you can do the below
        If tbl.Name <> "Table1" And tbl.Name <> "Table2" Then
            If MyTable Is Nothing Then
                Set MyTable = tbl 'set the table if not previously set
                Set MyWorksheet = sht 'set the worksheet if not previously set
            ElseIf tbl.ListRows.Count < MyTable.ListRows.Count Then 'if table rows is smaller than previously set one, reset
                Set MyTable = tbl
                Set MyWorksheet = sht
            End If
        End If
    Next tbl
Next sht
MsgBox "The Worksheet: " & MyWorksheet.Name & vbNewLine & "The Table: " & MyTable.Name, vbInformation, "Smallest Table in Workbook"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot as well.    To omit certain tables you can do the below
        If tbl.Name <> "Table1" Or tbl.Name <> "Table2" Then --> does it mean that I should the tables I want to count or the tables I dont want to count ?

Comment: @BernardDadie the tables that you don't want to count, hope it helps. :)

Comment: Hi Xabier, when I apply your code to my previous code, it somehow gives table 3 as the smallest table (it is true). However it does not take into account what I choose to omit. Maybe my code is repetitive, I'm not too sure.

Comment: @BernardDadie Could you share the code you used to Omit the specific tables?

Comment: I've posted it below @xabier

Comment: To omit certain tables you can do the below
        If ShortestTable.Name <> "Table2" Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table3" Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table5" _
         Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table7" Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table9" Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table11" _
         Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table13" Or ShortestTable.Name <> "Table15" Then

Comment: @BernardDadie I've updated my answer, instead of using `If ShortestTable.Name <> "Table2" Or` it should have been `And`, also in your post below, you have added all your previous code too, which won't be necessary if using my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following function loops over all tables of all sheets in a workbook. It returns the table with the least number of rows. To check the number of rows of a table, you can access the `Range`-property of that table and use `Rows.Count` of that range.

```
Function findShortestTable(wb As Workbook) As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet, table As ListObject, shortestTable As ListObject

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each table In ws.ListObjects
            If shortestTable Is Nothing Then
                Set shortestTable = table
            ElseIf table.Range.Rows.Count < shortestTable.Range.Rows.Count Then
                Set shortestTable = table
            End If
        Next table
    Next ws

    Set findShortestTable = shortestTable
End Function
```

You can call it for example like this:

```
Dim table As ListObject
Set table = findShortestTable(ThisWorkbook)
MsgBox table.Name
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Your help is very much appreciated. Another quick question, Imagine now I wan to only select certain tables and not all of them. How would you modify this code ?

Comment: Depends. How do you distinguish the "certain" tables from the rest?

Comment: say I only want to count table 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 and 14 for example